# My balance says 100. mBTC. How many bitcoins is this, and what is the value in British pounds?

Tags: wallet

Cant find an easy answer anywhere? I would like to know what this means and the value etc

---

Is it 0.100 bitcoin or 0.0100 bitcoin?

Comment: without specifying the software you used, I guess it is Bitcoin Core client. Then the "m" identifies "milli", or 1/thousands of a Bitcoin. Today Bitcoin comes with 8 digits after the point. So you could have 0.001 Bitcoins x 100 = 0.1 Bitcoin. And now what can it be in Pounds - you may want to look this up in coinmarketcap.com, I think the BTC is ~ 5400. So you would have 540 pounds. Please double check this, an then you might provide your own answer here.

Answer (score 3):

mBTC stands for the SI unit [Millibit](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Millibit) which is 1 thousandth of a bitcoin, or 0.001. So you have 100 mBTC * 0.001 BTC, or 0.1 BTC. The price of 1 BTC at the time of this writing on Coinbase in GBP is £5,485.21 to 1 BTC. Your 100 mBTC would then be valued around £548.

Comment: No problemo. Please consider marking this as the Answer so the question doesn't still look un-answered.